# how to pass session value from button click to another cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to attempt to perform a calculation on a button click on one asp.net form (invoice.aspx) then pass it to another response (print.aspx) form and insert that value into a label. However when ever I click the submit the value ends up being 0. No errors arise when this happens. Can this be done??

The following code I have is:

print.aspx.cs

```
public partial class print : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            lblDateIssue.Text = " Date Issue:" + date.ToShortDateString();

            var dueDate = date.AddDays(14);
            lblDueDate.Text = " DueDate:" + dueDate.ToShortDateString();

        double subTotal1 = (double)(Session["subTotal1"]);


        lblItem1Ttl.Text = subTotal1.ToString();
    }    
}
```

invoice.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["subTotal1"] = 0.0;
}

public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int qty1 = Int32.Parse(txtQty1.Text);
    double price1 = double.Parse(txtPrice1.Text);


    Session["subTotal1"] = (double)Session["subTotal1"] + (price1 * qty1);

}
```

}

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: I haven't done webforms in a while but here are too suggestions: 1) Wrap the assignment in your invoice.aspx.cs `Page_Load` method with an `if(!Page.IsPostBack) { ... }`. I feel like your `Page_Load` overwrites whatever you set in your `btnSubmit_Click` but I don't remember the lifecycle exactly. 1) Set a breakpoint in invoice.aspx.cs `btnSubmit_Click` and make sure that there really is a value being assigned to your session property.

Answer (score 0):

So rather than using the action attribute in the invoice.aspx form. I removed that attribute and put in `Server.Transfer("print.aspx", true);` to post to the response page on the button click event. I have also added the try - catch functions to stop the exception throwing. So thanks @dee-see because it was the life cycle just had to go a slightly different way to get around it. The full solution is below

invoice.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class invoice : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["subTotal1"] = 0.0;
            Session["subTotal2"] = 0.0;
            Session["subTotal3"] = 0.0;

        }

    }

    public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            int qty1 = Int32.Parse(txtQty1.Text);
            double price1 = double.Parse(txtPrice1.Text);
            Session["subTotal1"] = (double)Session["subTotal1"] + (price1 * qty1);
        }
        catch
        {
            txtQty1.Text = "";
            txtPrice1.Text = "";
        }

        try
        { 
        int qty2 = Int32.Parse(txtQty2.Text);       
        double price2 = double.Parse(txtPrice2.Text);
        Session["subTotal2"] = (double)Session["subTotal2"] + (price2 * qty2);
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        try
        {
            int qty3 = Int32.Parse(txtQty3.Text);
            double price3 = double.Parse(txtPrice3.Text);
            Session["subTotal3"] = (double)Session["subTotal3"] + (price3 * qty3);

        }
        catch
        {
            txtQty3.Text = "";
            txtPrice3.Text = "";

        }

        Server.Transfer("print.aspx", true);
    }
}
```

print.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class print : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            lblDateIssue.Text = " Date Issue:" + date.ToShortDateString();

            var dueDate = date.AddDays(14);
            lblDueDate.Text = " DueDate:" + dueDate.ToShortDateString();




        lblItem1Ttl.Text += "$" + (double)(Session["subTotal1"]);
        lblItem2Ttl.Text += "$" + (double)(Session["subTotal2"]);
        lblItem3Ttl.Text += "$" + (double)(Session["subTotal3"]);

        double total = ((double)(Session["subTotal1"]) + ((double)(Session["subTotal2"])) + (double)(Session["subTotal3"]));

        lblTotalAmount.Text += "$" + total;
    }


}
```